# Webscraping of Weather Website returns nil

Tags: web-scraping

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to take the temperature from The Weather Network however I receive no value for my temperature. Can someone please help me with this because I've been stuck on this for a while? :( Thank you in advance!

```
import time
import schedule
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def FindTemp ():
    myurl = "https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/36-hour-weather-forecast/ontario/toronto"

    headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'
   }
    r = requests.get(myurl, headers = headers)
    c = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
    all = soup.find("div",{"class":"obs-area"}).find("span",{'class': 'temp'})
    todaydate = time.asctime()
    TorontoTemp = all.text
    print("The temperature in Toronto is" ,TorontoTemp, "on", todaydate)
    print(TorontoTemp)

print(FindTemp())
```

Comment: It doesn't have to work at all, even if you didn't do anything wrong. Many sites use Javascript to fetch data, so you'd need to use some other scraper that has Chromium built-in and uses the same DOM that you'd see if you were interacting with the site yourself, in-person. And many sites with valuable data, such as weather data, actively protect themselves from scraping, since the data they provide has monetary value (i.e. you can buy the data feed access). In any case, you should start with some site that's known to scrape well. Beautifulsoup's own webpage is a good start :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to work at all, even if you didn't do anything wrong. Many sites use Javascript to fetch data, so you'd need to use some other scraper that has Chromium built-in and uses the same DOM that you'd see if you were interacting with the site yourself, in-person. And many sites with valuable data, such as weather data, actively protect themselves from scraping, since the data they provide has monetary value (i.e. you can buy the data feed access).

In any case, you should start with some site that's known to scrape well. Beautifulsoup's own webpage is a good start :)

And you should use a debugger to see the intermediate values your code generated, and investigate at which point they diverge from your expectations.